# Dispatcher and SynchronizationContext classes

Tags: wpf, dispatcher, synchronizationcontext

Can somebody tell me when to use a `Dispatcher` and when to use the `SynchronizationContext` class?

For a while now I have been using the `Dispatcher` to queue up tasks from a background thread, then I discovered the `SynchronizationContext`.

Answer (score 17):

AFAIK, when using WPF, the `SynchronizationContext.Current` object is of type [`DispatcherSynchronizationContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchersynchronizationcontext(VS.85).aspx) which is actually just a wrapper around the Dispatcher object and the `Post` and `Send` methods just delegate to `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` and `Dispatcher.Invoke`.

So even if you decide to use `SynchronizationContext` I think you end up calling dispatcher behind the scenes.

Besides I think it is a bit cumbersome to use SynchronizationContext as you have to pass a reference to the current context to all threads that need to call into your UI.

Answer (score 4):

1. Use the Dispatcher when your code is tightly coupled to WPF.
2. Use the AsyncOperationManager when you need to queue something on the 'Context' thread. This works with Windows Forms, ASP .NET and WCF applications as well.
3. Avoid using the SynchronizationContext yourself. The AsyncOperationManager uses this mechnism internally.

Comment: I realise you've written this answer some time ago. Nevertheless, I would be very interested if you could provide a concrete example how to use `AsyncOperationManager` to queue a delegate for execution on the "context" (UI) thread. I know how `SynchronizationContext` works; but I can't figure out how `AsyncOperation` is supposed to work. (I currently have the notion that it's rather like a "token" for keeping track of a asynchronous operation's state and progress, but won't help with actually scheduling a delegate for execution.)

Comment: How to use AsyncOperationManager: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/SyncContextTutorial.aspx

Comment: What if you need to synchronously run something on the UI thread? AsyncOperation doesn't have a Send() method but SynchronizationContext does.